# Excel VBA: find the last empty cell in an Excel table, not range

Tags: excel, vba

I found that the following code doesn't return the last used row number in that particular column.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(max_row, last_data_column + 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

What it returns is the last used row number in the Excel table.

I have an Excel table with the range A1:AB142. In the last row (142), only column B has data, the rest being empty. The above code returns 142, not 141, no matter what the last_data_column is (I tried 22, and 23).

Similarly,End(xlDown) doesn't work properly. Even though only W1 has data and the rest of the first row is blank,

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("W1").End(xlDown).Row
```

gives 2, when W142 is blank and W1 to W141 are not blank.

How to find the last empty cell in a particular column in an Excel table?,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.Find` method to find the last row with data in your table.

Then offset by one to fine the **last** empty row.

Something like (to get the last row):

```
    Dim LO As ListObject
    Dim C As Range

Set LO = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1")

With LO.Range.Columns(column_to_check) 'column_to_check is relative to the LO.Range
    Set C = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        'do stuff`
        Debug.Print C.Row+1 'last empty row
          'If the row is the last in the table, then column is full
    End If
```

To find the **First** empty row, something like:

```
With LO.Range.Columns(1)
    Set C = .Find(what:="", after:=.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext)
    If Not C Is Nothing Then
        'do stuff`
        Debug.Print C.Row 'First empty row
    End If
End With
```